# Use a String variable as argument from if sentence

Tags: c#

Good day everyone, 
I am new on c# and I just want to know if it is possible pass an string with the condition to an If sentence.

Something like the following:

```
String strEnviosCondicion = "!(drFilaMovimientos[\"EMISOR\"].ToString().Contains(\"CRUDO\") ||" +
                                                        "drFilaMovimientos[\"EMISOR\"].ToString().Contains(\"MEZCLA \")) && " +
                                                        "(drFilaMovimientos[\"RECEPTOR\"].ToString().Contains(\"CRUDO\") ||" +
                                                        "drFilaMovimientos[\"RECEPTOR\"].ToString().Contains(\"MEZCLA \")))";

 if (strEnviosCondicion)
 { Do Something }
```

Or it is mandatory on C# write the complete sentece

```
if (!(drFilaMovimientos["EMISOR"].ToString().Contains("CRUDO") ||
                                  drFilaMovimientos["EMISOR"].ToString().Contains("MEZCLA ")) && 
                                (drFilaMovimientos["RECEPTOR"].ToString().Contains("CRUDO") ||
                                 drFilaMovimientos["RECEPTOR"].ToString().Contains("MEZCLA ")))
                            {  Do Something }
```

Is there a way to perform this operation? (Replace the content of the conditional for an String Variable?

Comment: The second one. Why would you want to have the code in string format?

Comment: Why do you want to do this? refactoring or do you really **need** to inject code as a string?

Comment: Also, what you are looking is `Eval`. While C# doesn't support this, there are many [libraries](https://www.nuget.org/packages?q=eval) that offers this functionality. But, this is not a good approach to take, if you have other options to choose.

Comment: I don't suppose this is related the question that was posted a few hours ago (that has been deleted since), about getting C# code from a database and using it in an if statement?

Comment: @BrootsWaymb: it is a bit of a coincidence this question was posted shortly after the other one was deleted.

Comment: Is the `string` aspect of this critical, or is it the usage? Do you want to be able to store the function in a variable or do you want to receive it as external input?

Answer (score 2):

This is not possible, and in general, storing code in strings like this isn't ideal for many reasons (performance, readability, refactoring, reuse, security, ...).

How was the string generated? I would imagine it would comes from some kind of data structure, eg drFrilaKeys, and searchTerms (or could come from these), in which case, you would be better to express the expression programatically.

EG:

```
var drFrilaKeys = new string[] { "EMISOR", "RECEPTOR" };
var searchTerms = new string[] { "CRUDO", "MEZCLA" };
var allDrFilaMovimientosContainASearchTerm = drFrilaKeys.All(key => searchTerms.Any(searchTerm =>
    drFilaMovimientos[key].ToString().Contains(searchTerm)
));

if (allDrFilaMovimientosContainASearchTerm) {
 // Code here
}
```

### Other thoughts

If you are looking to store (eg) filters in a database or similar, it may be best to store them in a format (such as JSON) and parse that format into a boolean condition in code - I would strongly advise against any form of eval in production code. (Note - I'm not in general advising storing JSON in a relational database, but for certain limited flexible data which you don't wish to direct query, it can be a good choice. Certainly better than storing a string of C# in my mind).

Comment: Excuse my poor variable names / understanding of the code - my Spanish is rather non-existent!

Answer (score 0):

It looks like what you want is a function.

```
bool EnviosCondicion() {
    return !(drFilaMovimientos["EMISOR"].ToString().Contains("CRUDO")
        || drFilaMovimientos["EMISOR"].ToString().Contains("MEZCLA "))
        && (drFilaMovimientos["RECEPTOR"].ToString().Contains("CRUDO")
        || drFilaMovimientos["RECEPTOR"].ToString().Contains("MEZCLA "));
}

if (EnviosCondicion()) {
    do something;
}
```

If you're going to be testing different different strings for different values, you could add parameters to your function.

```
bool EnviosCondicion(string emisor, string receptor) {
    return !(emisor.Contains("CRUDO") || emisor.Contains("MEZCLA"))
         && (receptor.Contains("CRUDO") || receptor.Contains("MEZCLA"));
}

if (EnviosCondicion(drFilaMovimientos["EMISOR"], drFilaMovimientos["RECEPTOR"])) {
    do something;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to assign a function to a variable you can do that. The variable just wouldn't be a `string`. It would be a `Func`.

If this is your condition:

```
if (!(drFilaMovimientos["EMISOR"].ToString().Contains("CRUDO") ||
                              drFilaMovimientos["EMISOR"].ToString().Contains("MEZCLA ")) && 
                            (drFilaMovimientos["RECEPTOR"].ToString().Contains("CRUDO") ||
                             drFilaMovimientos["RECEPTOR"].ToString().Contains("MEZCLA ")))
```

...then what you're describing is a function that takes an `IDataReader` or `SqlDataReader` as a parameter and returns a `bool` indicating that the condition is true or false. (I'm guessing from `dr`.)

This would be represented as `Func<SqlDataReader, bool>`. That's a function that takes a `SqlDataReader` as an argument and returns a `bool`.

```
Func<SqlDataReader, bool> condition = (dr) => 
    !(drFilaMovimientos["EMISOR"].ToString().Contains("CRUDO") ||
                          drFilaMovimientos["EMISOR"].ToString().Contains("MEZCLA ")) && 
                        (drFilaMovimientos["RECEPTOR"].ToString().Contains("CRUDO") ||
                         drFilaMovimientos["RECEPTOR"].ToString().Contains("MEZCLA "));
```

Or you could declare the variable and assign a method to it:

```
Func<SqlDataReader, bool> condition = SomeCondition; 
// SomeCondition is a method with the same signature as the Func.
```

Then the usage would be

```
if(condition(dataReader))
```

That can be convenient if you might want to apply one condition or you might want to apply a different one. You can have a `Func` variable, assign one function or another to it, and then use the function.

And, just like any other variable, you can pass a `Func` as a method argument. So suppose you had a `SqlDataReader` and you wanted to first build a list of conditions and then check to see if they were all true. This example is a little bit clunky for a data reader, but for illustration:

```
var conditions = new List<Func<SqlDataReader, bool>>();
// we could add various conditions to this list:

// See if all of the conditions are true
if(conditions.All(condition => condition(reader)))
```

Imagine if we had conditions to determine *which* conditions we wanted to apply. That could turn into one massive, ugly condition. But representing individual conditions with variables can make them a little more manageable. It allows us to separate the steps of selecting the conditions from the step of checking them.